# Login control asp.net and CS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication, login-control

I have a question about ASP.NET and SQL Server database and using Visual Studio 2010. The problem is about the login control cs part.

I linked my form with database, need to compare login and password with ones in DB, but the line

```
SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
```

says that there is an error with syntax near "user"

Is it a query problem?

Can you help me please?

```
private bool UserLogin(string userName, string password)
{
    // read the coonection string from web.config 
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MidLinData"].ConnectionString;

    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        //' declare the command that will be used to execute the select statement 
       // SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT login FROM user WHERE userName = @login AND Password = @password", con);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT login FROM user WHERE userName = @login ", con);
        SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT password FROM user WHERE password = @password ", con);
        // set the username and password parameters
        com.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userName;
        SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
        //com.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = password;
        string result = rdr[0].ToString();

        // execute the select statment 
        //  string result = Convert.ToString(com.ExecuteScalar());
        //' check the result 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            //invalid user/password , return flase 
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // valid login
            return true;
        } 

        return true;
    }
}
```

Compiler says:

> Server Error in '/visualStudioWebsite' Application.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>
> Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 57:             // set the username and password parameters
>   Line 58:             com.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userName;
>   Line 59:             SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
>   Line 60:             com.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = password;
>   Line 61:
>
> Source File: c:\Users\annasolovjova\Desktop\visualStudioWebsite\login.aspx.cs    Line: 59

Comment: posting the error message from the compiler could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` is a **reserved keyword** in SQL Server - you're best bet is *not* to use it as a table name! And if you *insist* on using it, you **must** put it in square brackets:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT login FROM [user] WHERE userName = @login ", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both command like this:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
com.Connection = con;
com.CommandText = "SELECT login, password FROM user WHERE userName = @login and password = @password";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("login", userName); 
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", password);
```